# How to fix ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory?

Tags: java, apache-commons-logging

When i run the app it getting exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<clinit>(Dialect.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 1 more
```

I have put all the jar files in lib folder.
I don't know how to solve this, where is my mistake.

Comment: You have also added the commons-logging.jar?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Hibernate, you don't have Log4J on your classpath, and Hibernate expects Log4J to be available.

Comment: Consider using a framework like Maven, which will automatically download all necessary dependencies for you.

Comment: You should put commons-logging.jar in lib folder.

Answer (score 11):

Add this in your pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: for me it worked with `<version>1.1.1</version>` instead

Answer (score 1):

It works for me after adding this jar file

> commons-logging-1.2.jar

You can download it from [here](https://completejavakeypoints.blogspot.com/2017/07/how-to-fix-classnotfoundexception.html).

Comment: Excellent. Worked for me, but I would suggest downloading the jar directly from the maven repo ... https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2. Or if you are able use Gradle/Maven as this is then automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Include hibernate jar files (especially the required jars) in your `lib` folder

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: In my project the solution was to add the following jars of org.apache.commons:

commons-logging-1.2
commons-dbcp2-2.1.1
commons-pool2-2.4.2

Comment: downvoting with no explanation. terrible attitude

Answer (score 0):

For me problem solved post download & adding jar "commons-logging-1.2.jar"