# PDPageContentStream drwastring method is not working

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to create a new pdf document using a java program using the pdfbox API, but

> Exception in thread "main"
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Every time I am facing same error. I have already added external jar file to classpath, It is also showing that the `drawString` method of `PDPageContentStream` object is deprecated.

What could be the problem with this?

Comment: Have you taken care to also install the [PdfBox 1.8 dependencies](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html) or the [PdfBox 2.0 dependencies](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html)?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796112/how-to-fix-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-logging-logfactory